# Can masked passwords on iOS UIs be read?

Tags: passwords, mobile, ios

If someone had physical access to my iPhone, could they see the stored passwords for my WiFi or email that are represented as black circles and not actually the password itself, e.g. under my mail settings in the password field it shows `●●●●●`.

No one has had access to my phone but I just wondered. Similarly, if an iPhone was hacked during a phone call (which I have been assured [elsewhere](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128650/can-an-iphone-be-hacked-during-a-phone-call/) it cannot be but let's assume it could be) could the hacker remotely see these passwords, although I guess the answer will be the same to both.

Answer (score 2):

The phone should know these passwords if it wants to use it, so it obviously keeps them somewhere in a readable format. If the phone is compromised the attacker would be able to read them. That's actually why some mail providers (GMail, etc) are moving to oAuth so that the phone stores a revokable token instead of the actual password.

While that is possible, I don't think anyone is going to bother modifying the UI code to get what is hidden under the *** characters, rather they would directly get the value from where it is stored even before the UI is involved.

Comment: Please could you explain what is meant by "they would directly get value from where it is stored even before the UI is involved".

Comment: @Laura when you open the WIFI settings, the settings app reads the password from a file or a database before displaying it in a censored format. Rather than modifying the user interface code to undo the censoring and extract the value from there, the attacker will directly access the file/database and get the password from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a newer iPhone (> 4s) just turn on your passcode. It will encrypt all the data on the phone, so even if someone has access to your device, without the PIN / Password to the phone, it's useless.

Comment: my device requires a passcode to be entered to be used. Do you mean this protects my phone because no one should be able to guess my passcode and log in OR do you mean the passcode actually encrypts data so if someone did bypass it they could see the *** out passwords but nothing else?

Comment: @Laura the latter. Implementing a passcode turns on disk encryption. The most likely vector (as mentioned by others) is not that the user deobfuscates the black circles, but rather that they mount the phone from another device and poke around in the respective file locations. With the disk encrypted, they won't be able to access those locations.

Comment: so my passwords would be safe if my phone was ever in someone else's hands? Could I ask your opinion on whether an iPhone can be hacked during a phone call?

Comment: I saw your post from yesterday and I think the answer given is appropriate. Hacking a phone while it's in use (as a phone) is probably still a bit of a James Bond story line -for non-3LetterAgencies anyway ;)

Comment: @Hollowproc well actually some phones have their cellular network interface share memory with the main processor. Compromising the NIC would allow the attacker to compromise the main OS as well. But no such attack has been seen in the wild yet.

Comment: Encryption only protects data at rest. Once the phone is turned on and the password was entered at least once, the encryption key is kept in RAM and the partition remains decrypted (so the phone can continue working in background). If an attacker manages to execute malicious code once the partition is mounted he can still exfiltrate sensitive data.

Comment: @AndréBorie Arguments valid and accepted.

Comment: @Hollowproc Re hacking during a conversation, maybe with Mr Bond :) What if i was on the phone with apple whilst going through the iforgot process to reset iTunes password? As part of the process you receive a notification from apple asking to allow access to your phone to auto fill a verification number. This notification happens even if you don't phone them and follow online instructions- it is part of the process. They said it was ok to allow access BUT is this classed as an installation/ download & would it have compromised my phone's security to anyone out there in the digital ether?

Comment: @Laura hmmm interesting notion, but my guess is that this notification is going through an encrypted channel (SSL or other). That said, when you "Allow Access" you *are* creating a security exception, so proceed with caution when granting access to your device. From an eavesdropper perspective, its pretty unlikely and the timing would have to be perfect.