# Can malware transfer itself between iPhone and Windows laptop?

Tags: malware, windows, iphone, smartphone

I have an iPhone which I suspect was hacked. So, I have restored the iPhone using iTunes on my computer. When connecting my phone to my computer, can any spyware files transfer from the phone to my computer and vice versa?

If I already restored my iPhone but I connected it again to the laptop (assuming the laptop was infected), would it be possible for this infection to transfer itself to my phone?

Comment: This is a very broad question. In theory, yes it is possible. Any complex communication between two devices comes with the possibility of enabling lateral movement. However it's generally very rare. You don't have much to be worried about.

Comment: I took the liberty of removing the last question, since you should only ask one thing per question. But if you want an answer, see this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/128650/can-an-iphone-be-hacked-during-a-phone-call

Answer (score 0):

There are examples of virus/worm style software which has been able to bridge between systems on differing operating systems. Its certainly possible on a theoretical basis.

In practice the cost and effort required to author something this sophisticated puts it out of the reach of your average malware author. For a similar cost you could attempt to build something which bridges via a WiFi exploit and infect the laptop without ever needing the iPhone to be plugged in.

What is more likely is if your backup of the iPhone was from after the phone became infected and contains the infection. Depending on the infection vector its plenty possible for you to end up re-infected simply by restoring from it.

Comment: Hector, I didnt restore any backups. Im using the phone as a new one. Im just asking if connecting only can transfer this.